# SQL query to filter on group of related rows

Tags: sql, django, linq

I have a recurring problem in SQL queries, that I haven't been able to solve elegantly, neither in raw SQL or the Django ORM, and now I'm faced with it in EntityFramework as well. It is probably common enough to have its own name, but I don't know it.

Say, I have a simple foreign key relationship between two tables, e.g.

```
Book 1 <- * Tag
```

A book has many tags and a tag has one book, i.e. the Tag table has a foreign key to the book table.

Now, I want to find all books that have "Tag1" and "Tag2".

#### Raw SQL

I can make multiple joins

```
SELECT * FROM books
JOIN tags t1 on tags.book_id = books.id
JOIN tags t2 on tags.book_id = books.id
WHERE t1.tag = 'Tag1' AND t2.tag = 'Tag2'
```

Cool, that works, but doesn't really seem performant

#### Django

In django, I could do something similar

```
Book.objects.filter(tags__tag="Tag1").filter(tags__tag="Tag1")
```

Changing filters like that will cause the extra joins, like in the raw SQL version

#### EntityFramework LINQ

I tried chaining `.Where()` similar to changing Django's `.filter()`, but that does not have the same result. It will build a query resembling the following, which will of course return nothing, because there is no row where the tag are two different strings

```
SELECT * FROM books
JOIN tags t1 on tags.book_id = books.id
WHERE t1.tag = 'Tag1' AND t1.tag = 'Tag2'
```

#### Wrapping it up

I suppose I could do an array aggregate to aggregate tags into and array and compare to that, but that seems expensive too, and aggregates and grouping also have impact on the ordering of things, which forces me to do subqueries to get the order I want.

I am by no means an expert in SQL, as you can plainly see, but I guess what I am hoping for is either

1. A way to mimic the stupid nonsense above in LINQ
2. An alternative, more elegant approach that will let me do what I need and which works well with any ORM

#### Extra ramblings

This case where I need to find books that have "all of" a list of tags is the tricky bit... If it was "any of" or "this particular one", then it would be simple.

EDIT: The solution using arrays and overlap

In Postgres, we can do `array_agg` to aggregate all related tags into an array, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM books
JOIN tags t1 on tags.book_id = books.id
;

+--------+-------+------+
| BookId | Name  | Tag  |
+--------+-------+------+
|      1 | BookA | Tag1 |
|      1 | BookA | Tag2 |
|      1 | BookA | Tag3 |
|      2 | BookB | Tag1 |
|      2 | BookB | Tag3 |
+--------+-------+------+


SELECT books.BookId, Name, array_agg(t1.tags) as tags
FROM books
JOIN tags t1 on tags.book_id = books.id
GROUP BY BookId
ORDER BY BookId
;

+--------+-------+--------------------+
| BookId | Name  |        tags        |
+--------+-------+--------------------+
|      1 | BookA | [Tag1, Tag2, Tag3} |
|      2 | BookB | {Tag1, Tag3}       |
+--------+-------+--------------------+
```

With that, I can then use the array "contains" operator to find the row where `tag` overlaps with the expected set: `WHERE tags @> ('Tag1', 'Tag2')`.

This is also a viable option. It does aggregation instead of excessive joining. Not sure what that would look like with LINQ query though

Comment: `tag_list=['demo', 'test']` 
`Book.objects.filter(tags__tag__in=tag_list)` maybe this one?

Comment: @HemalPatel I think that's going to find books where tag is either demo or test

Comment: @TrueGopnik ok he wants book with all the tags in the filter right? `__in` wont work yes

Comment: Yes... "any of" would be simple. "all of" is the problem.. "only these" would be even more annoying

Comment: tag subquery with `__in` predicate and `count` aggregate filtered outside by `= 2` (number searched of tags) would do

Comment: @IvanStarostin Thanks. This was suggested in an answer below a couple hours after your comment. While this will work for this case, it is not the best approach for a general solution, since it may break in various ways... (see comment on the relevant answer below)

Comment: You say that a book has many tags and a tag has one book but on the extra ramblings tag1 is both on bookA and bookB. Can you please explain why?

Comment: It would help to know which platform you want to target primarily. If it's both SQL, Django and EF, this question is too broad because answers will probably only contain part of the solution.

Comment: @OrfeasBourchas: Sorry, I made a leap there. But the point is that the solution should work, whether it is 1-to-many or many-to-many

Comment: @GertArnold: It is all of them. I'm looking for a general approach... The SQL is most important, and the Django and EF specific implementations are just extra goodies (they become SQL in the end anyways)

Comment: Then please condense your question to ask for SQL only. No extra ramblings etc. Without the bounty, this question would have been closed as "needs more focus". You can't use a bounty to (temporarily) prevent a question from getting closed. I now added an answer you're apparently not looking for primarily.

Answer (score 3):

With `group by` and `having`, we can do `Tag 1` AND `Tag 2`:

```
with cte_tags as (
select book_id
  from tags
 where tag in ('Tag 1', 'Tag 2')
 group by book_id
 having count(*)=2)
select b.id as book_id,
       b.name
  from books b
  join cte_tags t
    on b.id = t.book_id;
```

EDIT:

1. If `tag` in `tags` for a `book_id` can be duplicated, use the following:

```
with cte_tags as (
select book_id
  from tags
 where tag in ('Tag 1', 'Tag 2')
 group by book_id
 having count(distinct tag)=2)
select b.id as book_id,
       b.name
  from books b
  join cte_tags t
    on b.id = t.book_id;
```

2. If looking for `tag1` OR `tag2`,  or `tag1` AND `tag2`, use the following:

```
with cte_tags as (
select book_id
  from tags
 where tag in ('Tag 1', 'Tag 2')
 group by book_id
 having count(distinct tag) between 1 and 2)
select b.id as book_id,
       b.name
  from books b
  join cte_tags t
    on b.id = t.book_id;
```

Comment: So query for books having "either" tag (not both), but then follow up with a count to make sure you only find the ones that have both... That would work, although also not very elegant. Also, to use this generally, in other situations, I need to be careful that there cannot by duplicate links. For instancing having two links to "Tag 1", or combining it with other joins which add duplicate row entries, so the `count(*)=2` will be incorrect... Not a bad solution... Thanks for chiming in :)

Comment: Use count(distinct tag)=2 if tag could be duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly you want books that *only* have tags 'Tag1' and 'Tag2'. I.e. no other tags. I'm not aware of an official name for this problem, maybe *exclusive contains*.

It amounts to finding books meeting two conditions:

- have all tags in ("Tag1", "Tag2")
- have two unique tags (or don't have other or zero tags)

You're looking for a solution that "works with any ORM". Of course, that's impossible. However, there is a LINQ solution that will probably work with any *LINQ-based* ORM. It works with EF anyway.

This query can be used when the tag names are not unique per book:

```cs
var tags = new[] { "Tag1", "Tag2" };
var books = context.Books
    .Where(b => b.Tags.All(t => tags.Contains(t.Tag))
        && b.Tags.Select(t => t.Tag).Distinct().Count() == tags.Count());
```

This, if the tag names are unique per book (which I assume):

```cs
var books = context.Books
    .Where(b => b.Tags.All(t => tags.Contains(t.Tag))
        && b.Tags.Count() > 0);
```

The second condition is necessary, otherwise books without any tags would also be selected (that's the semantics of `All`).

This generates SQL queries that you'll have to settle with (as with any LINQ-based ORM). For the second case, using EF-core 6:

```
  SELECT [b].[Id]
  FROM [Books] AS [b]
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM [Tags] AS [t]
      WHERE ([b].[Id] = [t].[BookId]) AND [t].[Tag] NOT IN (N'Tag1', N'Tag2'))
      AND ((
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM [Tags] AS [t0]
          WHERE [b].[Id] = [t0].[BookId]) > 0)
```

Of course it's possible to write SQL queries manually that do a (far) better job, performance-wise, in a specific constellation of indexes and statistics. Also, most (if not all) ORMs will offer a way to execute raw SQL. In that sense, a SQL query can be used with "any" ORM. I don't consider that an "ORM solution" though. It doesn't use the ORM's core machinery, merely its database connection.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is important, you should try various queries on your server with actual data and measure their performance.

I have a general note.

A query like this:

```
select book_id
from tags
where tag in ('Tag1', 'Tag2')
```

or like this:

```
select book_id
from tags
where tag = 'Tag 1' OR tag = 'Tag2'
```

usually would result in the scan of the whole table `tags` even if it had index on the `tag` column.

On the other hand, a query like this:

```
select book_id
from tags
where tag = 'Tag1'
```

would usually use an index.

So, we can  expand a query with `OR` into two separate queries and then combine their results.

```
WITH
CTE_BookIDs
AS
(
    select book_id
    from tags
    where tag = 'Tag1'

    INTERSECT

    select book_id
    from tags
    where tag = 'Tag2'
)
SELECT
    books.*
FROM
    books
    INNER JOIN CTE_BookIDs ON CTE_BookIDs.book_id = books.id
;
```

Here is a query over a sample data set:

```
CREATE TABLE #Tags
    (ID int IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,BookID int NOT NULL
    ,Tag varchar(50) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #Tags VALUES
(1, 'Tag1'),
(1, 'Tag2'),
(1, 'Tag3'),
(1, 'Tag4'),
(2, 'Tag1'),
(3, 'Tag2'),
(4, 'Tag1'),
(4, 'Tag2'),
(4, 'Tag3'),
(5, 'Tag3'),
(5, 'Tag4'),
(5, 'Tag5'),
(6, 'Tag1'),
(6, 'Tag3'),
(6, 'Tag5'),
(7, 'Tag2'),
(7, 'Tag3'),
(8, 'Tag1'),
(8, 'Tag2');

CREATE INDEX IX_Tag ON #Tags
(
    Tag, BookID
);

WITH
CTE_BookIDs
AS
(
    select BookID
    from #Tags
    where tag = 'Tag1'

    INTERSECT

    select BookID
    from #Tags
    where tag = 'Tag2'
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE_BookIDs
;

DROP TABLE #Tags;
```

**Result**

```
+--------+
| BookID |
+--------+
|      1 |
|      4 |
|      8 |
+--------+
```

**Execution plan**

[image: execution plan]

Comment: Hadn't though of using intersection in this way.. That would eliminate the need for including a filter on "count", which I definitely appreciate... I feel the counting thing may be a maintenance burden. So easy to make a mistake with that in a later edit.. The intersection idea is sound

Comment: A drawback of this method is that it's hard to generalize for a variable number of tags.

Comment: @GertArnold, you are right. Besides, after the number of tags increase above a certain threshold it would become faster to scan the whole `tags` table once instead of multiple index seeks and then merging the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try next solution:

First create index for speed up this query

```
create index on tags (tag, book_id);
```

Second, check next query

```
SELECT * FROM books
JOIN tags t1 on t1.tag = 'Tag1' AND t2.book_id = books.id
JOIN tags t2 on t2.tag = 'Tag2' AND t2.book_id = books.id;
```

If you want to deal with arbitrary list of any number of tags:

```
SELECT 
   books.id,
   count(distinct tags.id) as tags_count
FROM books
JOIN tags on tags.tag = ANY(['Tag1', 'Tag2', ...]) AND tags.book_id = books.id
GROUP BY books.id
HAVING 
   count(distinct tags.id) = <number of tags>
```

For speed up second query check if next index wil help

```
create index on tags (book_id, tag);
```